# NASM 16-bit: How do I wait for a key press for a limited amount of time?

Tags: assembly, x86, keyboard, nasm, wait

I am thinking if there is a way to wait for a key press for a certain amount of time. If there is no key press in 3 seconds time, the program will continue. Is there a way to wait for a key press and continue the program if there is no key press for 3 seconds?

Comment: I seem to recall you are writing code under DOS. If so then this answer would be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925577/3857942 . It could easily be modified to run with just the BIOS and you modify the interrupt tables directly. This latches on to the timer interrupt to avoid the hassle of having the BIOS tick count wrap around. The timeout for 3 seconds would be about 18.2*3 or about 55.

Comment: Here are two examples of timeouts in my 86 DOS / BIOS interfacing application: [one](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/f9d99182d0c5/source/serialp.asm#l412) and [two](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/f9d99182d0c5/source/debug.asm#l1868). This works by observing the change in the ROM-BIOS tick count. To avoid the wrap around problem mentioned by @Michael Petch, the only arithmetic done on the count is to detect changes to the low word. When the amount of configured changes has been detected we consider it timed out.

Comment: Here's another application of a timeout loop: https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/metakern/file/7799b7568c36/source/metakern/metakern.asm#l300 and here's the commit that adjusted this from doing tick count arithmetic to observing changes of the count: https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/metakern/rev/5ef8aaa2f87c

Comment: I'm hoping that there is a way without including the Interrupt Vector Table.

Comment: Here's a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596048/how-can-i-make-the-os-wait-a-second-before-shutdown-nasm/57622501#57622501 You just need to check for a keypress in the `.next` part.